# Creating a reverse dummy variable

Tags: python, pandas, numpy

I would like to create a reverse dummy variable from different columns of my dataframe.

The dataframe columns look like this:

```
client  booking_by_phone  booking_online  booking_online  ...  no_call_ad  no_sms_ad  no_ad_other
2q332   1                 0               0                    1           1          0
as4e3   0                 0               1                    0           0          0
ad222   0                 1               0                    1           0          0
q2x31   1                 0               0                    1           1          1
```

My current approach runs successful, but takes a really long time since I use `iterrows()`

```
for idx, _ in df.iterrows():
    if df.loc[idx, 'booking_by_phone'] == 1:
        df.loc[idx, 'bookingchannel'] = "phone"
    elif df.loc[idx, 'booking_online'] == 1:
        df.loc[idx, 'bookingchannel'] = "online"
    else:
        df.loc[idx, 'bookingchannel'] = "agency"
```

For the second variable it took even longer, since it is possible that user denied advertising for more than one channel, so I can't use elif:

```
for idx, _ in df.iterrows():
    df.loc[idx, 'ad_ban'] = 0
    if df.loc[idx, 'no_email_ad'] == 1:
        df.loc[idx, 'ad_ban'] += 1
    if df.loc[idx, 'no_mail_ad'] == 1:
        df.loc[idx, 'ad_ban'] += 2
    if df.loc[idx, 'no_call_ad'] == 1:
        df.loc[idx, 'ad_ban'] += 4
    if df.loc[idx, 'no_catalog_ad'] == 1:
        df.loc[idx, 'ad_ban'] += 8
    if df.loc[idx, 'no_sms_ad'] == 1:
        df.loc[idx, 'ad_ban'] += 16
    if df.loc[idx, 'no_ad_other'] == 1:
        df.loc[idx, 'ad_ban'] += 32
```

Is there a faster and easier way to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let's look at booking channel.  Here's a way with boolean masks:

```
df['booking channel'] = 'agency' # default value

mask = df['booking_by_phone'] == 1
df.loc[mask, 'booking channel'] = 'phone'

mask = df['booking_online'] == 1
df.loc[mask, 'booking channel'] = 'online'
```

You could create a list of tuples -- [('booking_by_phone', 'phone'), ('booking_online', 'online'), ...] and do the assignments in a loop.